# Hartshorne V Exercise 3.3: How to generalize I Ex 7.5?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The exercise is stated as follows:

> 3.3. Let $\pi: \tilde{X} \rightarrow X$ be a monoidal transformation, and let $D$ be a very ample divisor on $X$. Show that $2 \pi^{*} D-E$ is ample on $\tilde{X}$. [Hint: Use a suitable generalization of (I, Ex. 7.5) to curves in $\left.\Bbb{P}^{n} .\right]$

By applying V proposition 1.10, I can see that I just need to prove the following generalization of I Ex. 7.5:

> For any curve $C$ on $X\in \Bbb P^n$ and any point $P\in C$, we have $\mu_P(C)\le\deg(C)$.

(Here $\mu_P(C)$ is defined as follows: let $f$ be the local equation of $C$ at $P\in X$, then $\mu_P(C)$ is defined to be the largest integer $r$ such that $f\in m_{X,P}^r$. Besides, $\mu_{P}(C)$ is equal to the leading coefficient of linear Samuel polynomial:$\psi(l)=\text{length}(\mathcal O_{C,P}/m_{C,P}^l)$. )

When $n=2$(that's the case in Ex. 7.5), it's pretty easy since $C$ can be written as the vanishing locus of a single homogeneous polynomial. But for larger $n$ I don't know how to handle it...

Could you provide some help? Thanks!

Comment: Can you remind us what the definition of $\mu_P(C)$ is again? Further I think you may want $\leq$ rather than $<$ if I'm remembering the right concept of multiplicity - try a tangent line to a plane conic, for instance.

Comment: @HankScorpio Thanks for your advice, I have edited the post, and the definition is included.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to prove it in the case at hand:

Up to choosing a different linearly equivalent representative for $D$ which still passes through $P$, we may assume that $C$ and $D$ are two curves which share no common components and $\mu_P(D)>0$, where $\mu_P(D)>0$ as $D$ passing through $P$.
(We also note this preserves $C.D$ by theorem V.1.1 part (4).)
Then by exercise V.3.2, we have that $C.D=\mu_P(C)\mu_P(D) + \widetilde{C}.\widetilde{D}$.
Further, $\widetilde{C}$ and $\widetilde{D}$ do not share any irreducible components as $C$ and $D$ do not share any irreducible components, so by proposition V.1.4 and the definition of intersection multiplicity we have that $\widetilde{C}.\widetilde{D} \geq 0$.
Therefore $C.D \geq \mu_P(C)$ and we're done, as $C.D$ is the degree of $C$ under the embedding determined by $D$.

I think it should also follow from the intersection multiplicity at $P$ of $C$ and any hyperplane through $P$ being at least $\mu_P(C)$, but I didn't find a quick way to prove that (and the above was pretty doable).